# constructible subsets of noetherian spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Armand Borel in his set of notes "Linear Algebraic Groups" claims that it is possible to prove by noetherian induction that if $Y$ is a subset of a noetherian topological space $X$ with the property that its intersection with every irreducible closed subset $X'$ of $X$ contains an open dense subset of $\overline{Y\cap X'}$, then it follows that $Y$ is constructible.

Is anyone able to show me what the argument is?

Comment: You could have a look at proposition 6.C. In chapter 2 in the book matsumura's commutative algebra.